# Saltar seguridad Cloudflare Python, Scrapear MagicEden

Tags: python, seguridad, scraping

Desarrollé un script que scrapea con python la informacion de la api de magic
eden sobre todas las nuevas colecciones que se añaden, el problema viene en que han cambiado la seguridad Cloudflare y ha dejado de funcionar.
Lo curioso es que en mi pc personal va mas o menos, hay request que si saltan la seguridad y otras que no, es aceptable para lo que quiero hacer, por otro lado en mi servidor de netcup localizado en alemania no entra ni una request todas las bloquea cloudFlare, he mirado por todos lados y no hay manera.

```
while(True):
    ses = requests.Session()
    # ses.headers = {
    # 'referer': 'https://magiceden.io/',
    # 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36',
    # 'accept': 'application/json'
    # }

    ses.headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json'
    }
    scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(
        browser={
            'browser': 'chrome',
            'platform': 'windows',
            'desktop': True
        }
    )
    respuesta = scraper.get("https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/all_collections_with_escrow_data")
    print(respuesta.status_code)
    print(respuesta.text)
    time.sleep(3)
```

2ºIntento con Proxies, sigue saliendo error 403

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    
    
    while(True):

        proxies = {'http':'socks5://185.175.25.42:7497',
                    'http':'socks5://51.222.146.133:7497',
                    'http':'socks5://5.161.93.53:1080',
                    'http':'socks5://88.99.142.113:64806'}

        ses = requests.Session()
        ses.proxies=proxies

        ses.headers = {
            'accept': 'application/json'
        }
        scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(
            browser={
                'browser': 'chrome',
                'platform': 'windows',
                'desktop': True
            }, 
            
            sess=ses
        )
        respuesta = scraper.get("https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/all_collections_with_escrow_data")
        print("********************************************************************************************************************")
        print(respuesta.status_code)
        #print(respuesta.text)
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Y si son tus servidores los que están en lista negra?

Comment: Eso como puedo saberlo?

Comment: Prueba de usar proxy en el request. te paso gist para generarlos https://gist.github.com/zabbix-byte/c8d76f754d60725cf39e95800c086ffb @Chupitastiiks

Comment: @zabbix he metido los proxis con el generador que me has pasado, pero no hay manera no salgo de 403

Comment: @Chupitastiiks una cosa que verificaria es si tienes esto instalado pip install -U requests[socks] y despues ademas del status code el json que de da para saber si tienen algun tipo de seguridad que no permite los proxys.

Comment: Ten cuidado. Ahora mismo, la pregunta está _en el borde_ de lo que se permite en el sitio debido a que, esencialmente, te puedes estar volando términos de uso de Cloudflare, magiceden tiene un rate limit definido e incluso, hay territorios en los que [no es legal sin consentimiento de las partes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5193/web-scraping-ilegal/5194#5194). Puede terminar cerrada.